# Origen y uso de la frase "Para más inri"

Tags: modismos, coloquialismos

Acabo de leer en un diario español la frase "para más inri", y según el diccionario on-line que ofrecen, significa "por si fuera poco".

Yo nunca había leído ni escuchado tal frase.

Mi pregunta principal es: ¿es una frase usada y entendida solamente en España?

Como extra, me permito consultarle a quienes la conozcan o la usen, cuál sería su origen más plausible, o aquél totalmente descrito y documentado.

---

I've just read from a Spanish newspaper the phrase "para más inri", whose meaning according to their on-line dictionary is something like "if it wasn't enough" ("por si fuera poco").

This is the first time I read such a phrase.

My main question is: is this a phrase used and understood only in Spain?

As an extra for this question, I would like to know —from those who use or know it— what's its more probable or really known origin.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[INRI](http://dle.rae.es/inri) es un acrónimo que singifica *Iēsus Nazarēnus, Rēx Iūdaeōrum*, es decir, "Jesús de Nazaret, Rey de los Judíos". Según la tradición cristiana, tal y como aparece en la Biblia, la razón por la que Jesús fue crucificado era que se había erigido como rey de los judíos. Como parte de las burlas de los soldados, le pusieron una túnica morada (que implica estatus real), una corona de espinos e inscribieron en la cruz las susodichas siglas INRI.

Por eso, la frase "para más inri" se utiliza como "por si fuera poco", "para mayor escarnio", "para más ironía", etc.

En España la he usado y escuchado mucho. Desconozco su uso fuera de ella.